# .rda object not recognized in R vignette

Tags: r, error-handling, package, vignette

I am creating an R package, and have a graph.rda file inside my data folder.

In RStudio in the .rmd vignette file, I read the data in:

```
data(graph)
head(graph)
```

but when I "Knit HTML" the .rmd vignette file, I get an error on these above two lines saying:

```
"Error in head(sbTree): object 'sbTree' not found Calls: 
 <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> 
 eval -> eval -> head Execution halted"
```

I have tried researching for solutions and tried some of the suggestions (like adding library(knitr)), but to no avail.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!